# error status from popen when the command accesses a non existent file

Tags: c, popen, exit-code

Consider the following 2 lines of code

```
sprintf(comm, "cat %s.bz2 | bunzip2 -dc", string);  
fp = popen(comm, "r");
```

If I am opening a file and the file doesn't exist, I will simply get a NULL file. However if I use `popen` to pipe a file through `bunzip2`, if the underlying file doesn't exist, or is corrupt, then `fp` will have a valid pointer and not NULL. The obvious way to check would seem to be to check the exit status of the command run by `popen`, but this doesn't seem possible.

Is there an easy way to make `popen` return null if a command fails?

Comment: You should not commit UUoC ([Useless Use of `cat`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat)); you should be using: `sprintf(comm, "bunzip2 -dc %s.bz2", string);`.  At one level, for small files (say files less than a gigabyte in size), it probably doesn't matter.  If you're dealing with large files, it does affect the performance — you're making an extra copy of the data in the file unnecessarily.

Comment: If you want to read the contents of a bzip2-compressed file, you can just use the `<bzlib.h>` stdio-like API directly (`BZ2_bzopen()`, `BZ2_bzread()`, etc.) instead of messing with `popen()`.

Comment: The source code to @Shawn's comment is here: https://sourceware.org/bzip2/downloads.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *is there an easy way to make popen return null if a command fails?*

No.

It isn't [`popen()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/functions/popen.html)'s task to decide if a command it successfully ran (that is: started) failed. If a command is taken to have "failed" completely depends on the logical application level context it is run in/under.

Still, *if* `popen()` did not return `NULL` it *requires* a related call to [`pclose()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/functions/popen.html). The result of this latter call tells you the exit-status of what had been run by `popen()`. Using this exit-status the calling program can take any decision how to interpret the outcome of `popen()`, from success to failure.